# Trying to SSH using Python and fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, paramiko

I am really struggling to find a way to ssh to a server from my python script. I need to SSH to a server and yum install a specific package. I only need to run the following command:

Command I need to run:
yum install httpd

The script has a variable called internal_ip which has the IP we need to connect to and a variable called ssh_key for the SSH key.

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: Have you tried going through the [very simple example on fabric's front page](http://www.fabfile.org/)? If so, what exactly are you straggling with?

Comment: Yes, I have. My script has to create the fabfile before running it. It looks exactly as it should with the naked eye. However, I have to run dos2unix on the fabfile for it to work. So, I cannot see where my script is writing Windows style carriage returns.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python

bakery_internalip = "10.10.15.203"

print "[....] Preparing commands to run within fabfile.py"

fabfile = open("sfab.py", "w")
fabfile.write("from fabric.api import run, sudo, task\n\n@task\ndef myinstall():\n\tsudo('yum install httpd')")
fabfile.close

print "Running Fab Commands"

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', 'sfab.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'myinstall'])
#subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', '/home/ralawson/scripts/bakery/fabfile.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'deploy'])`

Comment: are you executing the script on windows? You should post a new question with these details - it's basically impossible to read that code on a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.  Run with `fab -f sfab -H localhost myinstall`

```
# sfab.py
from fabric.api import run, sudo, task

@task
def myinstall():
    sudo('yum install httpd')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it! Unfortunately, I have a little difficulty when trying to use your example within my script. However, if I create the fabfile manually, it works fine. Therefore, I believe the issue is with how I am writing the fab file in my script. I will send the code...

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python

bakery_internalip = "10.10.15.203"

print "[....] Preparing commands to run within fabfile.py"

fabfile = open("sfab.py", "w")
fabfile.write("from fabric.api import run, sudo, task\n\n@task\ndef myinstall():\n\tsudo('yum install httpd')")
fabfile.close

print "Running Fab Commands"

import subprocess
subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', 'sfab.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'myinstall'])
#subprocess.call(['fab', '-f', '/home/ralawson/scripts/bakery/fabfile.py', '-u ec2-user', '-i', 'id_rsa', '-H', bakery_internalip, 'deploy'])`

Comment: It works if I run dos2unix on the sfab.py which has been created by my script. I cannot work out where the extra carriage returns are coming from.